# Has the Appindicator or GtkMenu API changed in Saucy?

Tags: python, indicator, gtk

I've written a custom application indicator, which isn't working properly on saucy.

The menu is initialised with a few items, then updates regularly, adding or removing menu items.

This worked fine <13.10, but on 13.10, the line that adds the menu to the indicator produces the following warning:

```
Warning: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.38.0/./gobject/gsignal.c:2475: signal 'child-added' is invalid for instance '0x24390e0' of type 'GtkMenu'
self.ind.set_menu(self.menu)
```

And the items added to the menu subsequently dont appear.

[A bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glipper/+bug/1203888) has been filed against several indicators for the same problem, but it's not clear to me whether this is a problem with the indicators as a result of an API change, or a bug in the GTK or Appindicator libraries.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been investigating this bug further today and I found that even though adding menu items does not work, removing them still does. Therefore this is unlikely to be an intentional API change.

Comment: Please, show the investigation results.

Comment: They are on the bug report.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;dr: It is a bug.** Below are the reasons why it's a bug.

The bug was marked as **Triaged**, meaning: *Yeah, we acknowledge **there is a problem**. We will try to fix it when we have time.* **The bug** is filled against `libappindicator` source.

As can seen in [comment 8](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glipper/+bug/1203888/comments/8) **the bug is reproducible**. So, yeah, **everyone** is able to **see the problem**, and will be looking for a solution, or a [workaround (adhoc solution)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glipper/+bug/1203888/comments/16).

[Here is a briefing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Status) of what status means:

> **Triaged:**
>
> - A member of UbuntuBugControl believes that **the report describes a genuine bug** in enough detail that a developer could start working on a fix. (also see tip below)
> - Use this when you are confident that it should be looked at by a developer and has enough information

Comment: Thanks for your input, although your answer really just summarised what I'd already seen on the tracker, so didn't really answer my question as to whether it was a bug in the libraries or a change to the API.

Comment: @marxjohnson it is a bug. I'm not summarizing what is said in the bug report but telling you that it's a bug, confirmed and triaged. If it's triaged, needless to say, it's a problem that the developers are working on to look for solutions.

Comment: @marxjohnson also, when asking for suspected bugs or confirmation about bug reports (not when asking about the process of a bug itself, that's general to all bugs) please note that [AU is not the correct site to ask](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7543/169736).